# Ping computers when not joined to a domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am trying to understand windows domains. We connected a computer to the network and pulled an IP address. We were then able to ping a web server, however when we issued a GET request via a web browser, we received a 401.1 error.

My question is, why can we ping computers without being joined to the domain but not get the web service to work? When is the authentication information encapsulated in the packets?

Comment: Being able to ping a host has almost nothing to do with Web server authentication for Web service that is running on the destination host. With ping you check network connectivity. `401` is a response from a Web server meaning that authentication is required. It is part of HTTP. Ping uses ICMP. ICMP and HTTP are two different protocols having almost nothing to do with each other. I can not give you a full answer about Windows domain authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Your http request succeeded, network protocols work, but the get request was denied by the web server due to lack of credentials. This authentication is performed by the web server, and the web server is probably configured to use Windows Integrated authentication.

If you have the ability to configure the web server, there is a work-around here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/871179

Answer (score 1):

You have the order of protocol dependencies out of order. Look into the OSI model for an explanation how the different protocols interact. Here's a quick list of some protocols you'll see used.

1. Physical - is the network cable plugged in?
2. Data link - Ethernet, get a MAC address.
3. Network - IPv4 or 6 addresses, ICMP for ping.
4. Transport - TCP (80 or 443) or UDP.
5. Session - SOCKS proxy, sometimes seen in corporate networks.
6. Presentation - TLS, for encryption.
7. Application - HTTP or HTTPS to retrieve a HTML document. LDAP, Kerberos, DNS, for Active Directory (Windows domain).

You'll need some of the lower layers working before the higher layers work. For example, the network cable has to be plugged, and an IP address assigned before you can ping. You also need the network cable plugged in, and an IP address assigned, but you also need to open TCP port 443 and use TLS, before you can retrieve HTML documents, when using HTTPS.